# Suppose that $F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$ is finite for all $x$. Prove that $F$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a nonnegative, measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$ is finite for all $x$. Prove that $F$ is continuous.

**Observation:** Since $f$ is nonnegative, $F(x)$ is non-decreasing. Suppose that $F(x)$ is finite for all $x$, then $F(x)$ is uniformly bounded. Since $F(x)$ is non-decreasing and bounded, $F(x)$ converges to a limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$. **(Not sure if this is useful...)**

In order to show that $F$ is continuous, consider the definition of continuity by sequences. Thus, as $\{x_n\}\rightarrow x$, we need to show that $F(x_n)=F(x)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, i.e. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x_n} f(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt.$

Since $f$ is nonnegative and measurable, consider Monotone Convergence Theorem. **Here, I'm a little confused: In M.C.T., it's given a sequence of measurable functions that are increasing, nonnegative. What's the "sequence of functions" here?**

I'm not sure how to move forward...

Comment: @BenjaminMoss Can you explain why "bounded implies continuous?"

Comment: @DionelJaime What does $F(x)$ being finite for all $x$ mean then? Is it saying that $F(x)$ is bounded for each $x$, so it may not be uniformly bounded?

Comment: @MarkViola Why do we need "$f$ being nonnegative"?

Comment: All it's saying is that F(x) is defined for all x.

Comment: @DionelJaime Are you saying that "F(x) is finite for all $x$" does NOT imply $F(x)$ is uniformly bounded, or no need to use the fact that $F(x)$ is uniformly bounded we can still prove $F(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: I am saying the former.  However this implies the latter.

Comment: @MarkViola what if $f=1/\sqrt{x}$ if $x>0$? You cannot take the sup that easily

Comment: @fonfonx For that particular $f(x)$, the integral is not finite.

Comment: @DionelJaime of course it is $F(x)=2\sqrt{x}$ if $x>0$ which is finite for all $x$, even if its limit at $\infty$ is $\infty$. But if you want to avoid this limit take $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$ only and $0$ elsewhere

Comment: @2ndaccount I actually had the two mixed up, continuous implies bounded my fault.

Comment: @DionelJaime no because $f$ can be decreasing (as in my example).

Comment: @DionelJaime and you are saying that $\int_0^1 1/\sqrt{x} dx \leq 1*1/\sqrt{1} =1$ which is wrong, because this integral is equal to 2

Comment: @BenjaminMoss I don't think continuous implies bounded, but continuous maps compactness to compactness, then it's bounded.

Comment: @2ndaccount if f is a continuous function on a closed bounded interval to R this implies f is bounded

Comment: @BenjaminMoss   Yes.

Comment: @2ndaccount I had written the comment under the assumption that the integral was a Riemann integral.  If so, then the analysis in the comment was fine.  However, given that the tag is measure theory, the assumption of Riemann was flawed.  I've deleted my comment and it might benefit future readers if you deleted yours that reference the deleted comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_n \to x$, consider $f_n = f \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty, x_n)}$. 
Take $M=\max{x_n}$ and define $h=|f| \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty, M)}$.

Clearly $|f_n(x)| \leq h(x)$ for all $n$ and all $x$. Besides $h$ is integrable because $F(M)$ is finite.

Since $f_n \to f \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty, x)}$ pointwise you can use the dominated convergence theorem to say that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n \mathrm{d}\lambda \to \int_{\mathbb{R}}f\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty, x)}\mathrm{d}\lambda$$

which is exactly $F(x_n) \to F(x)$.

**Note**

I think the argument $|F(x+h)-F(x)| = |\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\mathrm{d}t| \leq |h|\sup_{[x,x+h]}f$ is incorrect, because $f$ can be unbounded. For example take $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x} \cdot 1_{(0,1]}(x)$.

Comment: Are you suggesting that MarkViola's comment was false?

Comment: I guess I am, I don't think you can conclude that $f$ is bounded

Comment: but is it true that the sentence "$F(x)$ is finite for all $x$ means $F$ is uniformly bounded? and if so, then $f(x)$ is only bounded a.e., right?

Comment: @2ndaccount, I don't think so. For example $x \mapsto x$ is finite for all $x$ but is not bounded

Comment: The that sentence is not saying for all $x$, but it is bounded for each individual $x$?

Comment: yes otherwise you say that $F$ is bounded and you don't mention $x$. You just know that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \ F(x) < \infty$, nothing more

Comment: Is $f$ being nonnegative important?

Comment: @2ndaccount I don't think so

Comment: @fonfonx If the integral is a Riemann integral, then the analysis in my now deleted comment was correct (Riemann integrable functions are bounded).  Inasmuch as you are interpreting the integral as a Lebesgue integral, then that comment is not valid.

Comment: @MarkViola yes sure. I indeed thought about this integral as a Lebesgue integral

Comment: @fonfonx Could you explain why $f_n \to f1_{(-\infty,x)}$ pointwise?